# How to debug a 503 error on an azure web app?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

When deployed locally my application works without any problems. I have been fighting with this error for 2 days on the azure deployment now:

Going to a link for my azure web app I get this error :

```
This page isn’t working
www.mypage.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503
```

Trying to attach the debugger yields : `Unable to find a process called dotnet with arguments .\Unikyte.SPA.dll. The process may still be starting, please try again.`

There doesn't appear to be anything useful written in the logs.

In detailed logs I found that every time I try to visit the page a new file is generated and it looks like this :[image]

Obviously the dotnet process isn't running, but by default after deployment it should run... Should I manually do dotnet run on my production dll?

Comment: You can try enabling stdout logging in web.config via Kudu. And then check out the logs.